# EasyAdmin 4 + VichUploader + oneupflysystem + AWS S3. Get image from private bucket

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle, flysystem

I'm using VichUploader and oneupflysystem to upload images to AWS server but when I config my vich_uploader.yaml there is uri_prefix, but i can't set there right pass to see the image on the form instead of that i have to generate presigned url. How could i do that to display the image on the form.

```yaml
vich_uploader:
  db_driver: orm
  storage: flysystem
  mappings:
    workout:
      uri_prefix:         bucket/exercise
      upload_destination: oneup_flysystem.aws_fs_filesystem
      namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
```

I've seen that we can rewrite a method of vichUploader bundle, but mb there is another decision.